# What does the "direction of data" mean in the context of Principal Component Analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, multivariate-analysis, linear-algebra

I am reading the Introduction to Linear Algebra 5th edition, section 7.3: Principal Component Analysis. The section contains the following sentence

> The first eigenvector $u_1$ of $S$ points in the most significant direction of the data.

What does the "direction of data" mean over here? I am guessing it implies a subspace. Also, why would an eigen vector point to it? Does it mean that the eigen vector is a part of the subspace?

Comment: Eigenvectors are defined only up to a nonzero multiple.  All the eigenvectors associated with a given eigenvalue, along with the zero vector, form a subspace.  Because these are concepts and results of linear algebra rather than of statistics, referring to a good linear algebra textbook might be of some help.

Answer (score 1):

Just prior to the line you quoted is another explanation.  Just above the line you quoted is this:

> The leading eigenvector of $\mu_1$ shows the direction that you see in the scatter graph of Figure 7.2.

...

> The SVD of A (centered data) shows the dominant direction in the scatter plot.

The first eigenvector is the direction of the maximum variance of the data.  It is not really a subspace of the data, but rather a rotation of the axes of the data such that the first axis (the first eigenvector) is aligned with the direction of maximum variance.  (Each eigenvector is a linear transformation of the original data space.)  The second eigenvector is then the direction of the maximum remaining variance conditioned on being orthogonal to the first eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

if you solve the equation of maximizing variance by choosing a vector subject to constraint $\Vert a\Vert = 1.$ Then the vector which maximizes this variance is the first eigen vector.

PCA is just an application of this property.

See [here](https://rich-d-wilkinson.github.io/MATH3030/3.4-svdopt.html) for more detail.